How to get rid of bold line in \multicols?
Trying to get rid of this bold line separator that comes with the \multicols command, my code looks like this:

I haven't been able to find a simple fix, I wouldn't mind if it was just a little thinner, the boldness of the line really messes with the overall look of my poster:

Any insight on this?

Reudce \columnseprule.  You can use \the\columnseprule to find the current value.

note the value is 0 by default so you have presumably set this already in some code not shown

@JohnKormylo this helped, thanks so much! Sorry for the stupid question lol I'm working in a rather lengthy template and it becomes hard to sift through what does what.

When all else fails, read the manual (for each package used).
